# How are duplicate questions deleted?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, automatic-deletion

[How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that) says that downvoted questions without upvoted or accepted answers will get automatically deleted if they are not closed as duplicates.

> 7. The system will automatically delete closed (not as a duplicate),
>      unlocked questions with zero or negative score having no upvoted or
>      accepted answers or pending reopen votes, that were closed 9 or more
>      days ago and haven't been edited in the past 9 days.

But what happens if duplicate question itself is bad, being downvoted and/or closed?

Are both questions eligible for automatic deletion after some time, or being duplicates prevents automatic deletion in that case?

---

For instance: following question is too broad, basically asks for code [Get random image from Image-Library in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32429824/get-random-image-from-image-library-in-swift) Now another user has asked basically the same question [How to show random image from photo library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36444853/how-to-show-random-image-from-photo-library) again being too broad, asking for code. Both questions are currently down voted.

What will happen to both questions if second one gets closed as duplicate of the first one?

Comment: That's just not possible, you cannot vote as dup when the dup target has no answer.  The comment merely made it *look* like somebody dup voted.  Not the case, it only has a "too broad" vote.  As-is, both will be automatically deleted.

Comment: @HansPassant I see.

Comment: @HansPassant just to note: you *can* dupe vote if the target doesn't have any answers *if* the questions are by the *same user*.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Duplicate targets can't be deleted so in your case both questions would survive automatic clean-up no matter how much the question and answers are down voted.

We (the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room) run into similar issues during tag-burnination. In cases where deletion is blocked by a complete duplicate chain of low quality questions we spend some manual delete votes to get rid of stuff when the roomba can't get at it.

If you're about to close a low quality, no value question as a duplicate of another similar low quality, no future value question you better think twice. Only vote as a duplicate if the question at hand is a good signpost to find the quality duplicate with great answers.

Comment: So moral of the story would be don't close vote as duplicate if other question is as bad as duplicate one.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I think it's more than that: don't close vote anything *that* bad as dupe, even if the duplicate target is good. Having a post saying "*problam nullpointeracception, halp plz very fast thx*", while could be duped, should not be, as it doesn't add any value to the site. I believe that well-formulated "sign-post" kind of duplicates generally shouldn't gather other kind of close votes on their own (maybe some too broad ones).

Answer (score 6):

The actual rules for deletion are [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/213575). There's a rule that reads:

> If the question is more than 30 days old, and ...
>
> ```
> has −1 or lower score
> has no answers
> is not locked
> ```
>
> ...or...
>
> ```
> it was closed and migrated to a different site
> ```
>
> ... it will be automatically deleted. Internally, these are termed
>   "dead" questions (RemoveDeadQuestions, or RemoveMigrationStubs in the
>   case of a migration).

Now, it doesn't says anything about closed or duplicated questions. What happens then? **The system ignores that!** It deletes any question with score -1 or less *and* without answers. If it's closed or edited or has 4564 comments doesn't affect the result. It will be deleted nonetheless as long as it doesn't has answers.

I agree with the last paragraph on [rene answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/320524/792066):

> If you're about to close a low quality, no value question as a duplicate of another similar low quality, no future value question you better think twice. Only vote as a duplicate if the question at hand is a good signpost to find the quality duplicate with great answers.

In other words, don't waste close votes on stuff that will end up deleted with a single downvote. That means that question with answers should be closed, unless you somehow get the answers that blocks deletion deleted.